# Why adding import `import cats.instances.future._` will result an compilation error for implicit Functor[Future]

Tags: scala, compilation, future, functor, scala-cats

The scala code is using cats and works well:

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.Functor
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Hello extends App {

  Functor[Future].map(Future("hello"))(_ + "!")

}
```

But if I add this import:

```
import cats.instances.future._
```

It will report such compilation errors:

```
 Error:(18, 10) could not find implicit value for parameter instance: cats.Functor[scala.concurrent.Future]
   Functor[Future].map(Future("hello"))(_ + "!")
```

Why it happens, and how can I debug it to find reason? I used all kinds of ways I know, but can't find anything.

The `build.sbt` file is:

```
name := "Cats Implicit Functor of Future Compliation Error Demo"

version := "0.1"

organization := "org.my"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

sbtVersion := "1.0.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.0.1"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object [`cats.implicits`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/implicits$.html) has the [`FutureInstances` trait](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/FutureInstances.html) as a linear supertype. The `FutureInstances` has an implicit `catsStdInstancesForFuture` method, which produces a `Monad[Future]`, which in turn is a `Functor[Future]`.

On the other hand, the object [`cats.instances.future`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/package$$future$.html) *also* mixes in `FutureInstances`, so it again provides an implicit method `catsStdInstancesForFuture`, but through another pathway.

Now the compiler has two possibilities to generate a `Functor[Future]`:

- by invoking `cats.instances.future.catsStdInstancesForFuture`
- by invoking `cats.implicits.catsStdInstancesForFuture`

Since it cannot decide which one to take, it exits with an error message.

To avoid that, don't use `cats.implicits._` together with `cats.instances.future._`. Either omit one of the imports, or use the

```
`import packagename.objectname.{member1name, member2name}`
```

to select only those implicits that you need.

---

Adding `"-print"` to `scalacOptions` *could* help when debugging implicits:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  ...
  "-print",
  ...
)
```

It will print out the desugared code with `cats.implicits.` and `cats.instances.`-pieces added everywhere. Unfortunately, it tends to produce quite a lot of noise.

---

The more fundamental reason why this happens is that there is no way to define higher-dimensional-cells (kind-of "homotopies") between the two (equivalent) pathways that lead to a `Functor[Future]`. If we had a possibility to tell the compiler that *it doesn't matter which path to take*, then everything would be much nicer. Since we can't do it, we have to make sure that there is always only one way to generate an implicit `Functor[Future]`.

Comment: Great answer, you explained everything I want to know, thank you so much!

Comment: `-print` gives me more sensible message and is very helpful

Comment: @Freewind Recall that `implicitly: Functor[Future]` can be used at various points of your code, if you want to find out whether an instance of `Functor[Future]` is available in the scope.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the instances are imported twice, meaning scalac cannot disambiguate between them and doesn't know which one to use and then fails.

So either you use the `implicits._` import or you import specific instances with `instances.<datatype>._`, but never both!

You can look at a more in depth look of cats imports here: https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html

Comment: Thanks I get it now, but I really want to know if there is any method to debug it without reading the document? Or even to find out which importing is duplicated? The compilation error is so helpless and scalac option `-Xprint:typer` also doesn't provide any useful information

Comment: I unfortunately don't know of such a way, though I recommend using either `implicits._` or `instances` then you won't run into this problem.